# creating dict where keys are alphabet letters and values are 1-26 using dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

```
alphaValueDict = OrderedDict.fromkeys(string.ascii_uppercase,range(0)
i = 1
for k,v in alphaValueDict.iteritems():
    alphaValueDict[k] = [i]
    i += 1
return alphaValueDict
```

I need to create an ordered dict , where the keys are all the letters in the alphabet and the values are from 1 - 26. My question is, how  can I use dict comprehension to do this in one line?

Answer (score 15):

You can avoid the dict-comprehension altogether:

```
>>> import string
>>> dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, range(1,27)))
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'g': 7, 'f': 6, 'i': 9, 'h': 8, 'k': 11, 'j': 10, 'm': 13, 'l': 12, 'o': 15, 'n': 14, 'q': 17, 'p': 16, 's': 19, 'r': 18, 'u': 21, 't': 20, 'w': 23, 'v': 22, 'y': 25, 'x': 24, 'z': 26}
```

With an `OrderedDict`:

```
>>> import string
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, range(1,27)))
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5), ('f', 6), ('g', 7), ('h', 8), ('i', 9), ('j', 10), ('k', 11), ('l', 12), ('m', 13), ('n', 14), ('o', 15), ('p', 16), ('q', 17), ('r', 18), ('s', 19), ('t', 20), ('u', 21), ('v', 22), ('w', 23), ('x', 24), ('y', 25), ('z', 26)])
```

I'd use a dict-comprehension only if you have to do some more computation to get the key/value or if it enhances readability (extreme example: `{noun : age for noun, age in something()}` gives you an idea of what we are talking about while `dict(something())` does not).

Comment: I will be repeatedly accessing the dict to get the value for each letter as I iterate over a list of of 5000 names, summing the total values of each name.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham In that case maybe using `ord` is simpler and more efficient. For each name do something like: `sum(map(ord, name)) - (ord('a') - 1) * len(name)`.

Comment: @Bakurlu, it is for project Euler. I actually started off doing that before I realized that  the values of the letters are specified as being from 1 to 26 in line with their position in the alphabet so ord would not work. unless I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You misunderstood my comment. `sum(map(ord, name))` will sum the ASCII value. If you subtract `(ord('a') - 1) * len(name)` you get the sum of the positions in the alphabet(since letters in ASCII are contiguous and in order). You could also write `sum(ord(letter) - ord('a') + 1 for letter in name)` where `ord(letter) - ord('a') + 1` is the position of `letter` in the alphabet. But since you subtract `ord('a')-1` from every element you can take it out of the summation (hence the `(ord('a') - 1) * len(name)`).

Comment: sorry yes I was not sure what you meant, I saw quite a few people did it your way in the solution forum.

Answer (score 4):

My take on it:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict((ch, idx) for idx, ch in enumerate(ascii_uppercase, 1))
```

Or:

```
from itertools import count, izip
od = OrderedDict(izip(ascii_uppercase, count(1)))
```

Comment: does count just increase in line with the length of the first argument in izip?

Comment: so I could not say make the values 2-4-6-8 by using count(2)?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham if you read the documentation, you'll see that it takes a step parameter, so `count(2, 2)` would count in 2s from 2...

Comment: thanks, I  need to get more familiar with itertools, a lot of questions I have asked have been answered using itertools

Answer (score 4):

```
theDict ={chr(y):y-64 for y in range(65,91)
print theDict
```

Output:

```
{'A':1,'B':2,......'X':24,'Y':25,'Z':26}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `enumerate()` to count the letters:

```
>>> OrderedDict((k,v+1) for v,k in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase))
OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('D', 4), ('E', 5), ('F', 6), ('G', 7), ('H', 8), ('I', 9), ('J', 10), ('K', 11), ('L', 12), ('M', 13), ('N', 14), ('O', 15), ('P', 16), ('Q', 17), ('R', 18), ('S', 19), ('T', 20), ('U', 21), ('V', 22), ('W', 23), ('X', 24), ('Y', 25), ('Z', 26)])
```

To answer the question at the end of the post, a dict comprehension is not an appropriate way to initialise an `OrderedDict`. Dict comprehensions only create ordinary dictionaries and if you use that to initialise your `OrderedDict` it is already too late, you have lost any ordering.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use zip and tuple unpacking

```
import string
{ k: v for k, v in zip(string.ascii_uppercase, xrange(1, len(string.ascii_uppercase)+1))}
```

Edited to take comments into account. It's a one liner, no dict comp.
Just relies on OrderedDict taking an iterable and the power of zip.

```
OrderedDict(zip(string.ascii_uppercase, xrange(1, len(string.ascii_uppercase)+1)))
```

Comment: Or skip the dict comprehension and just use `dict(zip(...))`.

Comment: also not an `OrderedDict`

Comment: True; the spec said "use a dictionary comprehension" though ;)

Comment: I always feel free to ignore a suggested implementation in the specification. Usually the customer has the wrong idea about implementation, but they may know what result they want.

Answer (score 2):

Using the basic:

```
>>> from string import ascii_uppercase
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
```

One liner:

```
>>> OrderedDict((k, i+1) for i, k in enumerate(ascii_uppercase))
```

Yields:

```
OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('D', 4), ('E', 5), ('F', 6), ('G', 7), ('H', 8), ('I', 9), ('J', 10), ('K', 11), ('L', 12), ('M', 13), ('N', 14), ('O', 15), ('P', 16), ('Q', 17), ('R', 18), ('S', 19), ('T', 20), ('U', 21), ('V', 22), ('W', 23), ('X', 24), ('Y', 25), ('Z', 26)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> s= string.ascii_lowercase

>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> odict = OrderedDict()
>>> for count,i in enumerate(s):
...     odict[count] = i
... 
>>> odict
OrderedDict([(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (5, 'f'), (6, 'g'), (7, 'h'), (8, 'i'), (9, 'j'), (10, 'k'), (11, 'l'), (12, 'm'), (13, 'n'), (14, 'o'), (15, 'p'), (16, 'q'), (17, 'r'), (18, 's'), (19, 't'), (20, 'u'), (21, 'v'), (22, 'w'), (23, 'x'), (24, 'y'), (25, 'z')])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print {chr(ele+97): ele+1 for ele in xrange(26)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using dictionary comprehension, a variation extending `dict` :

```
import string

class alph(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if len(key) != 1:
            raise ValueError("Not a character.")
        return string.ascii_lowercase.index(key.lower()) + 1
```

Handles both upper and lower and throws `ValueError` for wrong keys.